# Image is zero in every module homorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $A$ an $R$-module, and $A'$ is an $R$-submodule of $A$ such that for every $f \in \mathrm {Hom}_R(A,A')$ we have $f(A)=0$. Will this imply $A'=0$?

I am not sure whether it needs other criteria or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{R}$ are both $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and every homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ has an image of zero.

A sufficient condition is for $\hom_R(-,A')$ to be an exact functor,
since then $\hom_R(A,A')\to\hom_R(A',A')$ would be surjective, and
$\hom_R(A',A')$ contains the identity map, which must therefore be the zero map.

Comment: Although I can't see why "$\hom_R(A',A')$ *contains* $A'$ *via the constant functions*" (what constant functions?) the identity map is certainly in $\hom_R(A',A')$, so $A'=0$.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks: I miswrote my intent which was maps defined by $1\mapsto a$, which are definitely not in general constant functions.  I like your idea of looking at the identity map (though I tend to like arguments involving an injection to a zero object myself).

Comment: I can't see any multiplication on a module (excepting the one with scalars, of course).

Comment: @user26857 My mind and hands must have been well apart recently.  You are correct.  I mistook $A$ and $A'$ for rings.